# How to insert custom block to Draftjs Object?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

So.. I have a variable containing draftjs object

[Pic: draftjs object preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LauX0.png)

and my goal is to insert some custom block component at index number 2.
is there a way to achieve that?

P.S: the editor readOnly: true;

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: yes. this is day 2.